# Bash Script for Dump Several Processes on Android Devices

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have created three bash script for dumping several processes that runs in the Android device. 
The first bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "adb forward tcp:8888 tcp:8888"
adb forward tcp:8888 tcp:8888

exec $SHELL
```

The second bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "acquire the process with mem tool"
adb shell "
/dev/examiner/mem 797 | /dev/examiner/nc -l -p 8888
"

exec $SHELL
```

The third script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "dump the selected process"
nc 127.0.0.1 8888 > ~/work_folder/bin/797_surface_flinger.bin

exec $SHELL
```

For instance, I have 3 running processes: PID 797, PID 1025 and PID 2020 that I want to dump. Is there any idea to improve the second and third script without manually change the selected PID number for dumping the other selected processes?

Answer (score 0):

You can make each script accept 2 parameters, the port to use and the pid to use. 
Then run them with differing ports and pids.
For example, if the first script is called `script1` then you can run

```
script1 8888 797
script1 8887 1025
script1 8886 2020
```

Here are the scripts that use 2 parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash
port=${1?} pid=${2?}
echo "adb forward tcp:$port tcp:$port"
adb forward tcp:$port tcp:$port


#!/bin/bash
port=${1?} pid=${2?}
echo "acquire the process with mem tool"
adb shell "
/dev/examiner/mem $pid | /dev/examiner/nc -l -p $port
"


#!/bin/bash
port=${1?} pid=${2?}
echo "dump the selected process"
nc 127.0.0.1 $port > ~/work_folder/bin/${pid}_surface_flinger.bin
```

I dont know why you have `exec $SHELL` at the end of each script. Are you sure you need it?